# Writing dense sets in terms of set of integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we write every dense set in $\mathbb R$ as {$x_n$}$\mathbb Z$ , where {$x_n$} is a real sequence with limit $0$ ?

Comment: What does your notation $\{x_n\}\mathbb Z$ mean?  Any interpretation I could think of results in a countable set, which makes it unlikely to describe all dense sets.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ itself is dense and not countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any set $S$ of the form $\{x_n\} \mathbb Z$ has the property that if $s \in S$ then $2s \in S$.  It's very easy to find dense sets that do not have this property.